# Cryptocurrency historical prices

Tags: data-request, finance, historical

I'm looking for cryptocurrency historical data, including prices and market cap (either from exchanges or average price) of the main cryptocurrencies, namely: Bitcoin, Ripple, Litecoin, Ethereum, Dash.

So far I've only been able to find [this source on Quandl](https://www.quandl.com/data/BAVERAGE?keyword=bitcoin) and [the historic daily price on blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/charts/market-price?showDataPoints=false&timespan=all&show_header=true&daysAverageString=1&scale=0&format=csv&address=)

Any additional additional sources for other cryptocurrencies and more detailed data (like hourly price or Open-High-Low-close) will be helpful.

Ideally the data should go back as far as possible but realistically data since 2012 would be enough. As for younger cryptocurrencies 1 or 2 years will suffice.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As it turns out there are several resources one can use for all main cryptocurrencies so I will post here the most relevant and flexible I was able to gather.

**All Cryptocurrencies**

Coinmetrics

https://coinmetrics.io/data-downloads/

This page has data for: Bitcoin, Litecoin, Ethereum, NEM, Decred, ZCash (transparent transactions only), Dash, Dogecoin, Ethereum Classic, PIVX, Monero.

ETH -  BTC

[Poloniex As chart](https://poloniex.com/exchange#btc_eth)

[Poloniex As JSON](https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=BTC_ETH&start=1435699200&end=9999999999&period=14400)

One needs to edit the timestamps in the API to get a different snapshot. And edit the period to adjust the details.

**Bitcoin**

[Coindesk Closing price and OHLC](http://www.coindesk.com/price/)

[Closing price blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/charts/market-price?showDataPoints=false&timespan=all&show_header=true&daysAverageString=1&scale=0&format=csv&address=)

[Bitcoin data on Quandl](https://www.quandl.com/data/BAVERAGE?keyword=bitcoin)

[Bitcoin data on Quandl II](https://www.quandl.com/collections/markets/bitcoin-data)

**Ether**

Thanks to the answer to [this question on Ethereum's stackexchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/635/ether-historical-prices)

[Etherchain's API](https://etherchain.org/api/statistics/price)

I will keep updating this answer with more links as I find them.

Comment: hi i'm a total newbie just one question, regarding the Poloniex as JSON file the first line i get is[{"date":1439006400,"high":50,"low":0.0045001,"open":50,"close":0.004555,"volume":329.6493784,"quoteVolume":54434.7809242,"weightedAverage":0.00605585}. Whats that format for "date" ?

Comment: That's UNIX time also called POSIX time. It can be translated to ISO 8601 which is more readable. "date":1439006400 -> Sat Aug 08 04:00:00 2015 UTC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: How about https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/

Comment: How long are poliniex time series?

Comment: Victor: any API is fine, cryptocompare, coinmarketcap, poloniex and many others have similar data. I'd go with the one you feel most comfotable with. fccoelho: Time series keep growing over time, just click on the link and see for yourself the current length.

Comment: It seems many APIs are limited to the day's OHCL etc. i.e. Whenever I provide a POSIX/epoch like https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricehistorical?fsym=XVG&tsyms=USD&ts=1514070631 the API only has the choice to return the OCHL or average for that day and not the price at my exact time of trade like 13:35. Where can I find an API that can give me the price for an exact time? Any free public APIs that can do this?

Comment: all the sources provided here offer only end of day price, did you find the **hourly** rates of cryptos? or I am missing something?

Answer (score 27):

The [Historical price data link](http://www.coindesk.com/price/) for Bitcoins on CoinDesk.com  lets you download a CSV starting 18 Jul 2010.

I found this by simply Googling 'bitcoin history'

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this source. I wish Coindesk had the same information for all the other cryptocurrencies.

Answer (score 9):

I work at Quandl and stumbled upon this post. I'm happy to share an update: we now have two databases which contain OHLCV (open-high-low-close-volume) data for bitcoin and other cryptocurrencies:

1.Brave New Coin Digital Currency Indexed EOD: https://www.quandl.com/data/BNC2 Contains historical global price indexes for a number of cryptocurrencies

2.Brave New Coin Liquid Index: https://www.quandl.com/data/BNC1 Contains the first true historical price for bitcoin, built specifically for institutional use. History goes back to 2010.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The datasets are amazing. It's great to see more and more cryptocurrency datasets on Quandl.

Comment: Thanks, wacax! Please do let us know if you have any questions or need any help with the databases.

Comment: "The publisher of this dataset has restricted all usage to subscribers only." applies to both links above.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.CryptoDataDownload.com is newer but has 28+ exchanges, ~550 pairs, 8+ ccy pairs, and daily/hourly/minute timeframes to download via csv format for free

Answer (score 1):

There also seems to be https://quantfund.club/ now, though they are pretty new but have raw trade history for all kinds of currencies...

Answer (score 1):

There are many services that provide OHLC aggregated data for crypto markets both free and paid and in many cases exchanges themselves provide APIs to access that kind of aggregated data (like BitMEX for example), but if you're looking for more granular, high resolution historical tick-by-tick data there isn't that much of a choice or it's very expensive.

You can also check out https://tardis.dev/ which I've build out of necessity (as couldn't afford paying really expensive competition offers) to gather and process tick level data. It supports all top (by real volume) exchanges.

Answer (score 0):

Many cryptocurrencies are also available on the Quandl platform from **[Bitfinex](https://www.quandl.com/data/BITFINEX-Bitfinex)**

See [other quandl answers](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=quandl) for how to access with the API.