# Total cryptocurrency market cap over time

Tags: data-request, api, finance, historical

Does anyone know where to download historical data for the total market capitalization of the cryptocurrency ecosystem? For example, the data behind the "Total Market Capitalization" chart here: https://coinmarketcap.com/charts/.

Their API only allows access to the current market cap, not historical data. I've tried contacting them, but thought I would ask here as well. I would like to avoid calculating it myself if possible...

P.S. I've seen [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6884/cryptocurrency-historical-prices) but no one suggested a source for the market cap data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @philshem suggested I wrote some python to gather the data

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Create date range for historical snapshots
Date = pd.date_range(start='20130428', end='20171210', freq='7D').strftime('%Y%m%d')

# Retrieve market cap value in dollars
market_cap = []

for date in Date:

    # Retrieve historical snapshot data from date
    page = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/historical/'+date)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    # Extract marketcap value from span
    market_cap.append(int(re.sub(r',|\$', '', soup.find('span', {'id' : 'total-marketcap'}).text.strip())))

# Create data frame of data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Total Market Cap':market_cap}, index=Date)

# Write data to file
df.to_csv('total_market_cap.csv')
```

This gets the total market cap value from each snap shot which is taken each sunday.

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore ... Do you know if it would be easily fixable ?

Comment: Last of what I saw Coinmarketcap were making an API, perhaps there's an API available now for use.

Answer (score 3):

Scraping your link is not too difficult, because the raw data is in the source code.

First, create a list of all possible dates, from this URL

https://coinmarketcap.com/historical/

```
['20130428','20130505','etc...']
```

Then loop over each date and download the raw HTML. From each file, like `20130428.HTML`, you can see the raw data in the source. Here's an example of BTC from that date:

```
<td class="text-left col-symbol">BTC</td>
<td class="no-wrap market-cap text-right" data-usd="1261032047.28" data-btc="11114671.5035">$1.26 B</td>
```

corresponds to this view in the browser

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Bitcoin only, this page offers download links:

http://data.bitcoinity.org/markets/market_cap/all/USD?t=l

Maybe contact the site owner for more data, seems to be a single person.