# Cryptocurrency historical data OHCL daily

Tags: data-request, finance

Cryptocurrency historical data OHCL daily

I would like to download historical dataset CSV form 
BTC ETH LTC ETC BTS

Comment: Some explanations of the many abbreviations would help. And what about [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6884/cryptocurrency-historical-prices)?